# What difference does getting an input inside a loop make?

Tags: python, while-loop

I was running a code in python and was wondering what difference does getting an input inside a loop make.

For example;

```
restart = ('y')
chances = 3
balance = 1000
while chances >= 0 :
 pin = int(input('Please enter your 4 digit pin \n'))   
 if pin == (1234):
    print('You have entered the correct pin')
    while restart not in ('N', 'n'):
        print ('Press 1 to check balance')
        print ('Press 2 to withdraw')
        option = int(input('Can you please enter your option \n'))
        if option == 1:
            print('Your balance is', balance, '\n')
            restart = input('Do you like to go back?')
            if restart in ('n', 'N'):
                print ('Thanks')
                break
```

In the code above, when I had
`pin = int(input('Please enter your 4 digit pin \n'))`  outside while loop ,
`if restart in ('n', 'N'):`, this if statement did not work. It started printing
`print('You have entered the correct pin')` without terminating.

Can someone explain why?

Comment: Use a debugger and step through your code to see what it does. `break` breaks the innermost loop only. Why would you think the flow of execution would move *before* the outermost while-statement? The if-statement does work. Why shouldn't it work?

Comment: Asking for input inside a loop will ask for input more often than outside a loop. That's exactly what you observed: outside the loop it asked only once and reused the same pin each time, inside the loop it asks several times.

Comment: Is there some code missing from the example? chances is assigned a value but never used.

Answer (score 0):

You're outer while loop never terminates. Currently you're looping when `chances >= 0` yet you never change it's value after you initialize it to 3. So if pin is not set to '1234' you'll be left in the outer loop forever.

If pin is set to '1234' You'll go through the inner logic at least once because restart is set to 'y'. Once you set restart to `n` you'll break out of the inner loop. However you'll now be stuck in the outer loop with restart set to a value that will prevent you from entering the inner loop again. Se above for why you'll never be able to exit this loop.

All moving the pin input outside the loop does is make sure that there is no way to choose an alternate value if you enter an incorrect one.

Comment: While your statement is true, that's not what OP asked for, IMHO

Answer (score 0):

u need to break the while loop.

```
restart = ('y')
chances = 3
balance = 1000
while chances >= 0 :
 pin = int(input('Please enter your 4 digit pin \n'))   
 if pin == (1234):
    print('You have entered the correct pin')
    while restart not in ('N', 'n'):
        print ('Press 1 to check balance')
        print ('Press 2 to withdraw')
        option = int(input('Can you please enter your option \n'))
        if option == 1:
            print('Your balance is', balance, '\n')
            restart = input('Do you like to go back?')
            if restart in ('n', 'N'):
                print ('Thanks')
                
    break #<----------- here.
```

Answer (score 0):

The "break" gets you out of the inner while loop `while restart not in ('N', 'n'):`.

Since "Restart" value would be 'n' \ 'N', you'll never go in this loop again, But the outer loop `while chances >= 0 :` keeps going because you never changed the value of chances.